# distributed hardware monitoring using puppet

Tags: puppet, distributed

I'm planning to design a distributed hardware monitoring and controlling like provisioning user Environments,decommission, push updates etc. i herd puppet supports these features. Please let me know if there is a better freeware out there ? . or a good puppet reference.

Comment: .... you could always google for `Puppet reference`... also, you are being pretty vague on what your are trying to "design"....

Comment: thanks man, i think I've found the best reference already.